# How do get last data in group by using linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

In my table i have a property detail. Each property has agent name. I want to group by agent name and take last inserted row of each agent. I used below code but it gives first row values.When i use lastordefault it display error. Any one have any idea

```
 var property = (from n in properties select n).GroupBy(x => x.agentname)
              .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
              .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).OrderByDescending(x => x.datecreated).Take(20);
```

Comment: `.Where(g => g.Count() == 1)` produces 1 record

Answer (score 0):

First of all your first query makes no sense to me i.e. `(from n in properties select n)` you can directly apply `GroupBy` on `properties`. Next, you are selecting first record from the group and applying `OrderByDescending` on complete result which will do nothing as you have just 1 record.

This should give you expected result:-

```
var property = properties.GroupBy(x => x.agentname)
                         .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(z => z.datecreated)
                                       .FirstOrDefault());
```

This will return a collection containing `last inserted row of each agent`.

Comment: How can we get date in orderbydescnding

Comment: @RahulSingh There is no `x.datecreated` after `GroupBy` (x is `IGrouping<...>`) :)

Comment: @IvanStoev , OP - Yes my bad! Corrected thnx.

Comment: @r.vengadesh - Did you get a chance to look at my answer?